# Double axis Data Grid

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, .net

So, basically i am creating a page which will view all the details of a contract, part of this will be a financial review, i want the top axis to be years and the left axis to be details e.g.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      
    </td>
    <td>
      <strong>2014</strong>
    </td>
    <td>
      <strong>2015</strong>
    </td>
    <td>
      <strong>2016</strong>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <strong>Income</strong>
    </td>
    <td>
      2014 Data
    </td>
    <td>
      2015 Data
    </td>
    <td>
      2016 Data
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <strong>Expense</strong>
    </td>
    <td>
      2014 Data
    </td>
    <td>
      2015 Data
    </td>
    <td>
      2016 Data
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <strong>Surplus</strong>
    </td>
    <td>
      2014 Data
    </td>
    <td>
      2015 Data
    </td>
    <td>
      2016 Data
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

What would be the best way to display this with boundfields?

So in a way that i can treat it almost like a grid view where i can say

```
table.DataSource = GetData();
table.DataBind();
```

EDIT:
Just to clarify,  i DO NOT want a table, i'm looking for a .Net element that will display data in the same way as this table if that's possible at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check out bootstrap.css. They have some hard coded values for css that work much like a table works. They have a cool grid style system as well as hundreds of other predefined css values and JS values.
here is a direct link to their grid system build: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks! I'll have a look at it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use data repeater as well which gives you the same grid look but it does create a table (I believe so...). Take a look at

[Introduction to the DataRepeater Control (Visual Studio)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488280.aspx)

[Displaying Data with the DataList and Repeater Controls (VB)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/data-access/displaying-data-with-the-datalist-and-repeater/displaying-data-with-the-datalist-and-repeater-controls-vb)

[Easily display data with the Repeater control in .NET](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/easily-display-data-with-the-repeater-control-in-net/)